# Calculate area bounded by 3 curves (integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that the area of bounded by the function $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ and the inverse function of $f$ and the line $y=-x+2$ is equal to $\require{cancel} \cancel{A=4(2-a^{2}).}$

$a$ is the x of point of intersection between $f(x)$ and $y.$

Edit: Here's what I tried

I noticed that area can be split into 2 area; first one is the area bounded by $x=0$ and $x=f(a)$ and $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ and 2nd is the area bounded by $x=f(a)$ and $x=a$ and $f(x)$ and $y$. I tried then to calculate $A=\int_0^{f(a)} \lvert f(x)-f^{-1}(x)\rvert \,dx\ +\int_{f(a)}^a \lvert f(x)-y\rvert \,dx\ $ while I could integrate it was hard to simplify to $4(2-a^{2}).$

[image: graph of the 3 curves]

Comment: Your work on the subject ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I added it now

Comment: Very well !....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you a simple way by considering the polygon $P$ defined by

$$(0,0),(a,0),(a,f(a)),(f(a),a),(0,a)$$

whose area is ${\frak A}(P)=a^2-\tfrac12(f(a)-a)^2$ (a square minus a triangle).

Let $$I=\int_0^{a}f(x)dx=a+e^{-a}-1=a-f(a)$$

Now, let us express that, with $A$ the area of the curvilinear triangle (your notation)

$$A+2I={\frak A}(P)$$

I leave you the final computation of $A$.

Caution : it cannot be given by the formula you give because, as $a \approx x=1.27846454$, formula $A=4(2-a^2)$ gives a result $\approx  1.4621141$, visibly much too large !

Comment: See "Caution" at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm sure now that the formula $A=4(2-a^{2})$ is wrong after computing using your method and other methods

Comment: $$A={\frak A}(P)-2I=\tfrac32-a+\tfrac12a^{2}-\tfrac12e^{(-2 a)}-e^{(-a)}-ae^{(-a)} \approx 0.3655284 $$